# in numpy, what is the difference between calling MA.masked_where and MA.masked_array?

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array

Calling `masked_array` (the class constructor) and the `masked_where` function both seem to do exactly the same thing, in terms of being able to construct a numpy masked array given the data and mask values. When would you use one or the other?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import numpy.ma as MA

>>> vals = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
>>> cond = vals > 3

>>> vals
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

>>> cond
array([False, False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

>>> MA.masked_array(data=vals, mask=cond)
masked_array(data = [0 1 2 3 -- --],
             mask = [False False False False  True  True],
       fill_value = 999999)

>>> MA.masked_where(cond, vals)
masked_array(data = [0 1 2 3 -- --],
             mask = [False False False False  True  True],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

The optional argument `copy` to `masked_where` (its only documented optional argument) is also supported by `masked_array`, so I don't see any options that are unique to `masked_where`. Although the converse is not true (e.g. `masked_where` doesn't support `dtype`), I don't understand the purpose of `masked_where` as a separate function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You comment:

> If I call them with inconsistently shaped value and masked arrays, I get the same error message in both cases.

I don't think we can help you without more details on what's different.

For example if I try the obvious inconsistency, that of length, I get different error messages:

```
In [121]: np.ma.masked_array(vals, cond[:-1])
MaskError: Mask and data not compatible: data size is 5, mask size is 4.
In [122]: np.ma.masked_where(cond[:-1], vals)
IndexError: Inconsistent shape between the condition and the input (got (4,) and (5,))
```

The test for the `where` message is obvious from the code that Corralien shows.

The `Masked_Array` class definition has this test:

```
        # Make sure the mask and the data have the same shape
        if mask.shape != _data.shape:
            (nd, nm) = (_data.size, mask.size)
            if nm == 1:
                mask = np.resize(mask, _data.shape)
            elif nm == nd:
                mask = np.reshape(mask, _data.shape)
            else:
                msg = "Mask and data not compatible: data size is %i, " + \
                      "mask size is %i."
                raise MaskError(msg % (nd, nm))
```

I'd expect the same message only if the shapes made it past the `where` test, but were caught by the Class's test.  If so that should be obvious in the full error traceback.

Here's an example that fails on the `where`, but passes the base.

```
In [138]: np.ma.masked_where(cond[:,None],vals)
IndexError: Inconsistent shape between the condition and the input (got (5, 1) and (5,))
In [139]: np.ma.masked_array(vals, cond[:,None])
Out[139]: 
masked_array(data=[--, 1, --, 3, --],
             mask=[ True, False,  True, False,  True],
       fill_value=999999)
```

The base class can handle cases where the `cond` differs in `shape`, but matches in `size` (total number of elements).  It tries to reshape it.  A scalar `cond` passes both though the exact test differs.

Based on my reading of the code, I can't conceive of a difference that passes the `where`, but not the base.

All the Masked Array code is python readable (see the link the other answer).  While there is one base class definition, there are a number of constructor or helper functions, as the `where` docs makes clear.  I won't worry too much about which function(s) to use, especially if you aren't trying to push the boundaries of what's logical.

Masked arrays, while a part of `numpy` for a long time, does not get a whole lot of use, at least judging by relative lack of SO questions.  I suspect `pandas` has largely replaced it when dealing with data that can have missing values (e.g. time series).

Comment: Thank you. I will mark this as accepted because it contains a specific example of where the output may differ depending which is used. By the way, I now can't reproduce my observation that the two gave the same error (my comment on the other answer, which you quoted), but maybe somehow it was an environment with a really old numpy, as I distinctly remember the misspelling "Inconsistant" in the error message, which I see used to exist in the code base.

Answer (score 3):

[`masked_array`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/8cec82012694571156e8d7696307c848a7603b4e/numpy/ma/core.py#L6617) is an alias for the [MaskedArray](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/8cec82012694571156e8d7696307c848a7603b4e/numpy/ma/core.py#L2692) class. When you use it, there is no verification of parameters.

[`masked_where`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/8cec82012694571156e8d7696307c848a7603b4e/numpy/ma/core.py#L1828-L1947) is a function that creates an instance if `MaskedArray` that checks your parameters.

```
def masked_where(condition, a, copy=True):
    """[docstring]"""
    # Make sure that condition is a valid standard-type mask.
    cond = make_mask(condition, shrink=False)
    a = np.array(a, copy=copy, subok=True)


    (cshape, ashape) = (cond.shape, a.shape)
    if cshape and cshape != ashape:
        raise IndexError("Inconsistent shape between the condition and the input"
                         " (got %s and %s)" % (cshape, ashape))
    if hasattr(a, '_mask'):
        cond = mask_or(cond, a._mask)
        cls = type(a)
    else:
        cls = MaskedArray
    result = a.view(cls)
    # Assign to *.mask so that structured masks are handled correctly.
    result.mask = _shrink_mask(cond)
    # There is no view of a boolean so when 'a' is a MaskedArray with nomask
    # the update to the result's mask has no effect.
    if not copy and hasattr(a, '_mask') and getmask(a) is nomask:
        a._mask = result._mask.view()
    return result
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps, but can you give an example of where the two would give different results because of this? If I call them with inconsistently shaped value and masked arrays, I get the same error message in both cases.

Comment: I think you should take a look at @hpaulj's answer.

Comment: Thanks very much. I've accepted hpaulj's answer as it gives an example of when the results differ, but your answer is also helpful for understanding what is going on.